# UNIX: Pattern match and sort

Tags: perl, bash, unix

**Input**

```
1   DX
    ADA
4   O1
3   I1
    C1
2   LA
    FTAS
    TT66
```

**Expected Output**

```
1   DX
    ADA
2   LA
    FTAS
    TT66
3   I1
    C1
4   O1
```

**Command**

> sort -n Input

I tried sorting the file numerically as mentioned above . But it sorted the null values as well , which messed up the strcuture. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you need to treat non-numbered lines as belonging to numbered ones. What about such solution, assuming that '%' sign does not appear in input?

```
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ cat bzz.txt 
1   DX
    ADA
4   O1
3   I1
    C1
2   LA
    FTAS
    TT66
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ cat bzz.txt |perl -0pe 's/\n /%/g'
1   DX%   ADA
4   O1
3   I1%   C1
2   LA%   FTAS%   TT66
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ cat bzz.txt |perl -0pe 's/\n /%/g' | sort -n |perl -0pe 's/%/\n /g' 
1   DX
    ADA
2   LA
    FTAS
    TT66
3   I1
    C1
4   O1
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$
```

In this solution, first newlines are removed, to keep non-numbered assigned as one to numbered ones, and then, after sort, newlines are brought back to their original place, therefore output looks like only numbered ones were sorted. AFAIR This is called "multiline pattern" matching.
I'm not sure if it shouldn't be moved to superuser.com

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -nwe 'if (/^(\d+)/) { $num = $1; } $a[$num] .= $_; 
           END { print for grep defined, @a }' input.txt
```

Simply use an array to store the lines according to the line number found, or the last number if no number is found. Then print the array. If you do not use the warnings switch `-w` you do not need to use `grep defined`, since the warnings will be on unused array elements (0 in this case).

In the case of duplicate line numbers, it will append the lines to the previous entries, which is kind of handy. It also does not require any kind of sorting, since array elements are already sorted.

Answer (score 1):

This output keeps track of the latest initial number, and appends the current line onto the appropriate element of a hash. The data in the hash is output in numerical order of the keys.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $n;
my %data;
while (<DATA>) {
  $n = $1 if /^(\d+)/;
  $data{$n} .= $_ if $n;
}

print $_ for map $data{$_}, sort { $a <=> $b } keys %data;

__DATA__
1   DX
    ADA
4   O1
3   I1
    C1
2   LA
    FTAS
    TT66
```

**output**

```
1   DX
    ADA
2   LA
    FTAS
    TT66
3   I1
    C1
4   O1
```

---

**Update**

You may prefer this alternative method, that reads the entire file, splits it after every newline that is followed by a digit, and sorts those records in numeric order of the initial number. The output is identical to the previous solution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/;
print for sort {
  my ($aa, $bb) = map /^(\d+)/, $a, $b;
  $aa <=> $bb;
} split /(?<=\n)(?=\d)/, <DATA>;

__DATA__
1   DX
    ADA
4   O1
3   I1
    C1
2   LA
    FTAS
    TT66
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can with `sort` alone, I would process it with `sed` or similar and pipe it into `sort` and back again.

Comment: Technically there's always a way, but sometimes the need is over-sophisticated, and cost of solution simply makes it not worth to achieve it with some even-more-sophisticated "trick".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `sort` alone expects a list, and the data is in a file, so clearly it cannot be done without any other operators. But it is certainly possible with a single `sort` *statement*.

Comment: Being in a file is irrelevant as `sort` takes a file as input, so I am not sure what you mean by you not understanding what I mean. I was simply trying to indicate to process the file with sed, awk, perl, python, whatever you want --- pipe it into sort --- and pipe it back again in a similar fashion to what @PiotrWadas did.